# HTML form actions

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text, input

For input style "text", I have a javascript function such as:

```
document.getElementById("dds1").onkeyup = function() {

    updateIt();
};
```

Now, what if I had a checkbox? What would the code look like? What about for radio buttons? What would I use to get values (for the checkbox, either checked or not checked. and for the radio buttons, I'd like to get which button is clicked).

Here is code for the radio button:

```
<li id="foli517"        class="     ">
<label class="desc" id="shippingChoice" for="Field517_0">
    Shipping Options
        </label>
<div>
<input id="shippingChoice" name="Field517" type="hidden" value="" />
    <span>
<input id="shipping1"       name="Field517"         type="radio"        class="field radio"         value="$2.00 Shipping Fee"      tabindex="13"                        checked="checked"                      />
<label class="choice" for="Field517_0"      >
    $2.00 Shipping Fee</label>
    </span>
    <span>
<input id="Field517_1"      name="Field517"         type="radio"        class="field radio"         value="I will pick up the items (free shipping)"        tabindex="14"                               />
<label class="choice" for="Field517_1"      >
    I will pick up the items (free shipping)</label>
    </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the checkbox:

```
document.getElementById("checkBox").onclick = function() { 
    var isChecked = this.checked; 
    //whatever
};
```

For the radio button:

```
document.getElementById("radioButton").onclick = function() { 
    var clickedId = this.id;
    //whatever 
};
```

Comment: I updated the code. Please see above. Can you implement a function that does the following if the user has selected the radio button corresponding to "$2.00 shipping fee": document.getElementById("shippingSpan").innerHTML = "$2.00";

Comment: @resing1 You could do it a number of ways - given that you have an id on each radio button, the easiest way is `document.getElementById("aSpecificRadioButton").onclick = function() { document.getElementById("shippingSpan").innerHTML = "$dollarAmountForThatRadioButton";  };`